# What is the name of the case that uses dot separators

Tags: naming-conventions, camelcasing, pascalcasing, snakecasing

There are:

- `camelCase`
- `UpperCamelCase` (aka `PascalCase`)
- `snake_case`
- `kebab-case`

but is there an official name for this `case.with.dots`?

Comment: What language are you using which uses dot separators?

Comment: This is mostly a format  you will find for files. e.g. `my.model.json` instead of `MyModel.json` or `my_model.json`.